# Limit scrolling in excel 2003 vba

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to limit the rows in an excel workbook to only a certain range.

This is what i have so far:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Run (Limit)

End Sub
```

and:

```
Sub Limit()
Worksheets(Quotation).ScrollArea = "A1:N54"
End Sub
```

Any help would be appriciated!!!!

Comment: If I take the above example then why not hide the rows from 55 onwards till the very end?

Comment: what is your question? `ScrollArea` is working well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the above was not working for me was because `workbook_open()` doesn't work in Excel 2003 whereas:

```
Sub auto_open()

Sheets(1).ScrollArea = "A1:N54"

End Sub
```

Works and this is what i am using now.